# RSA encryption/decryption process is not working correctly

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

I'm trying to apply the RSA cryptosystem to encrypt a byte `M=72`, using predefined modulus `n`, public key exponent `e` and private key `d`.

`(n, e, d, p, q) = (4802, 5, 59, 43, 8)`

In order to accomplish that, I used the following code on Python console:

```
C=(M**e)%n
M=(C**d)%n
print M
```

- the first instruction encrypts the byte as C: using the RSA encryption mathematical expression (`**` stands for exponentional, and `%` for modulus in Python programming language)
- the second decrypts C to get M back: using the RSA decryption mathematical expression.

However, the output shows:

> 2816

which means that M was incorrectly computed as '2816', although I'm pretty sure that all the values of `n`, `e`, `d`, `p` and `q` respect the RSA public key algorithm specification.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: [factor 4802](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+4802), are you sure the $n=4802$

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: did you click to the link and see the factors? see [Text book RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa)

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, so since the number has more than 2 prime divisors, I think I made a  mistake for computing `n`.

Comment: $q =8$, must be prime too.

Comment: @kelalaka Obviously `p*q` is different from `n`,  and `q` is not prime number.

Comment: @kelalaka Yep, I noticed that too.

Comment: On top of the answer: A) `n` is some million (.. dozens words "million" suppressed) million times too small to provide security. B) `M=(C**d)%n` won't work even if you increase `n` by a million million. See [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) or/and use the three-argument form of [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). C) With the question's textbook RSA, a message guess can be checked; think of e.g. a name on the class roll. See [encryption padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Public_key_cryptography).

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks for your help, B) Regarding the modular exponentiation, I know that `C**d` performs the exponentiation and `%n` applies the modulus.  Why it won't work if n is increased by million? A+C)  I'm not understanding what you're talking about. sorry.

Comment: On B): because no computer has enough memory to store `C**d`exactly for `n` large enough for security, which implies nearly as large `C`and `d`. Modular reduction must be applied as the exponentiation is performed. Three-arguments `pow` does, but `(C**d)%n`does not. On A): `n` needs to be MUCH larger, otherwise it can be factored and an adversary can then decipher just as easily as the legitimate recipient. On C): with the question's textbook RSA, if you know that the name of a student is enciphered, you can encrypt each name on the class roll and see which matches the ciphertext.

Comment: @fgrieu I understood, this is very important. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RSA definition requires $n = p q$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

In your example $n=4802$ has a factorization as;

$$ n = 2 \cdot 7^4$$ with 10 divisors. Also, your $q=8$ is not a prime.

---

Here a working example for you with  [fips.186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf#page=62) standard, or see [$\lambda$ versus $\varphi$ in RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29591/lcm-versus-phi-in-rsa);

- Select two distinct random primes;  $p = 47, q = 43$
- compute $n = 47*43 = 2021 $
- compute $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)= \operatorname{lcm}(62,42)= 966$
- select $e$;

  - $e=3$;
  - $gcd(3,966) = 3 \neq 1$ chose another;
  - $e=5$
  - check $gcd(5,966) = 1$, ok.
- $d = 773$ by $d = e^{-1} \bmod{\lambda(n)}$

As noted by [Fgrieu](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63315/rsa-encryption-decryption-process-is-not-working-correctly#comment140347_63315) on the comments, make sure that you are using efficient methods. For example;

- For finding prime numbers probabilistic [Miller–Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), should be enough. Note that Miller–Rabin primality test is probabilistic; composite output is always true, prime output has [probability](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41224/probability-that-n-is-prime-such-that-n-fails-the-miller-rabin-test-n-times) defined by the number iterations.
- For [modular multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) there are various chocies as  $2^k$-ary sliding window algorithm used by [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/), left-to-right or right-to-left modular multiplications.
- Modular inverse by the [extended-gcd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

---

**Calculating with Wolfram Alpha**

One can use the highlighted text to enter at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) with your paramaters:

- $\lambda(n):$   `CarmichaelLambda(2021)` result is 966
- $gcd(5,966):$   `gcd(5,966)` result is 1
- $d:$            `5^-1 mod CarmichaelLambda(2021)` result is 773
- encrypt $m=65:$ `65^5 mod 2021` result is c=168
- decrypt $c=168:$ `168^773 mod 2021` result is 65

**Note:** if you are using textbook RSA then change `CarmichaelLambda()` with `phi()`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm facing the same problem given: `(n, e, d, p, q) = (289, 77, 133, 17, 17)` and `M=72`. n is prime as well as p and q. Moreover I verified that `(e * d) mod ((p-1)*(q-1)) = (77×133) mod (16×16) = 1`

Comment: you took p =q, there I said distinct primes.

Comment: My bad, I missed that .. sorry.