# RSA How to select a value K such that $e d = 1 + k \varphi(N)$ holds

Tags: rsa, public-key

I am learning RSA cryptography. The part I am stuck on is understanding how k and the public exponent $e$ is selected.

Given the formulas;

Decrypting: $c^d \bmod N = (m^e)^d \bmod N$
Which is equal to m the message

Encrypting:
$m^e \bmod N = c$

My question is when generating the private exponent how do we find what the public exponent should be and what k should be in the formula

$$d = (1 + k*\varphi(N))/e$$

I understand it has something to do with the inverse of modules but I don
t get the math behind it.

Comment: You can find examples in this site as [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63315/rsa-encryption-decryption-process-is-not-working-correctly/63317#63317) and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definiti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to $e$ and $\phi(N)$ (which have to have gcd equal to $1$) and we get $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$xe + y\phi(N) = 1$$

The $x$ (taken modulo $\phi(N)$, if needed) is the $e$ you are looking for. The $k$ is totally irrelevant for encryption/decryption, but it's actually the $y$ in the above equation (rewrite your equation and see).

Comment: HI, so a question I am working on asks to find d given the public key N and e. But I didn't think it was possible unless you knew what p1 and p2 are so you can find phi(N). I am given e and N but not p1 or p2 so how do I find what d is?

Comment: I am trying a couple things to figure out how to find D given e and N so if I am doing something wrong just let me know.

Comment: @User You cannot, unless it's a puzzle with a special trick. Like taking $d$ too small, or $N$ being easily factorisable etc.

Comment: I think your right since N is a small number.

Comment: Ok so I factored N and got phi(N) so to find d I guess I do d = e^-1 mod phi(N)

Comment: Given that I know e and phi(N) I am not sure how to calculate the inverse?

Comment: @User Apply the extended Euclidean algorithm, as I said. The wiki link I gave has a description.

Comment: @User https://wolframalpha.com also does modular inverse for you. Or the Crypto modulo in Python. etc.